# How the search works in neo4j?

Tags: search, neo4j, relational-database, graph-databases

If we want to find a person details using the `personName` in `neo4j`, we need go through all the `nodes` that are with `label` `person`. But in `relational database` we can do it just by going to the `person table` and finds the record. So, how this searching works in `neo4j`? I mean

1) Is it first finds all the nodes with `label` `person` and than searches in those `nodes` to match with the `personName`

OR

2) Searches every `node` on the way it encounters, than if the `label` is `person` than checks for `personName`. If not matches than goes to another `node` and so on..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a schema index on label `:Person` and property `personName` (`CREATE INDEX ON :Person(personName)`) the following cypher statement will be a done by a simple index lookup:

```
MATCH (n:Person{personName:'John'}) RETURN n
```

If the index does not exist, Neo4j will iterate over all nodes having the `Person` label and filter them by their property (which is somehow comparable to a full table scan in relational world).

Comment: can you please tell me how this index works in neo4j